# What is the nearest underwater hotel to Germany?

Tags: germany, hotels, factoids

I'm trying to find an underwater hotel that is not too far away from Germany. What's is the nearest one?

Comment: I think there is not one available, a lot of them are announced, but I couldn't find any. Take a look for example at this page which claims to be the first underwater resort, however, it is not yet available: http://www.poseidonresorts.com/

Comment: @RoflcoptrException  [Utter Inn](http://www.unusualhotelsoftheworld.com/utterinn) is not really big, but I think it could count as underwater hotel

Comment: NEAREST by which citerion?

Comment: @MarcelC. distance(beeline). If Germany is too vague, let say the distance from Frankfurt

Comment: OK. That's useful too know.

Comment: I read it like "what is the nearest **underwear** hotel". Glad I read it again to get it right..

Comment: A new one has just opened off the island of Zanzibar: http://www.bbc.com/travel/feature/20131119-an-underwater-hotel-opens-in-africa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [Utter Inn](http://www.unusualhotelsoftheworld.com/utterinn) in Sweden. From the most [northern point of Germany](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=utter%20inn%20sweden&aq=0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=nl&sa=N&tab=wl) it is 755 km

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be only one currently in operation: [Jules Underwater Lodge](http://www.jul.com/) actually is underwater and it is located in Key Largo, FL in the USA. [You can read more about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_habitat#La_Chalupa_research_laboratory)

The resort that @RoflcopterException mentioned in the comments [Poseidon Resorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseidon_Undersea_Resorts) never appeared to have gotten off the ground and would have been located in Fiji.

There are more concrete plans in Dubai to create another [Underwater Hotel](http://www.underwaterhoteldubai.net/) based on designs by a [Deep Ocean Technology](http://www.deep-ocean-technology.com/home/projects/underwater_hotel.html)(I think) company out of Gdynia but again money seem to be be the issue.

[Atlantis Dubai](http://www.atlantisthepalm.com/) offers Underwater Suites though they are not actually under water.  Just appear to be that way from inside.

P.S.  If you feel like sifting through the [rumor mill](http://www.hotelchatter.com/tag/Underwater%20Hotels) there is a lot of chatter about various underwater hotels.